# How to use nmap (Zenmap) to check if my port is open?

Tags: nmap

Im developing a Unreal Engine game and Im trying to make a quick test by sending my packaged build to another player, for this I need to forward the port 7777, I think I achieved that in my router, but Im unsure how to use Zenmap to check this out, before bothering players with tests.

This is the only "open" result I get when checking for it:

PORT STATE SERVICE 7777/tcp open cbt MAC Address: 02:0F:B5:8F:2F:44 (Unknown)

All other results are either closed or filtered.

Does this mean its closed?.

Comment: I'm not getting your question. the port appears to be open per your nmap scan. when you are scanning your target, is the target the public IP of the router? are you testing from inside or outside of your network? its often not possible to test port forwarding from inside your network (unless your router supports hairpinning/NAT Loopback).